Unable to install Opentext VTS on centos
While trying to install VTS getting ./inst64.bin: exec: line 3319: /tmp/install.dir.9244/Linux/resource/jre/bin/java: not found on centOS.
I have a JDK previously installed into the system and added into path, but still facing this issue, upon checking the location stated in error the jre is present there.
